# Why are statistical assumptions not reported in published journal articles?

Tags: model, assumptions

In universitiy theses I often see students including details about their model in the appendix (distribution residuals, heteroscedasticity, durbin watson, multicolinearity values). However in published journal articles the statistical assumptions are often not even mentioned (atleast in my field of economics). What is the reason behind this? Is it because most of the time it doesn't add value?

I included the statistical assumptions of my model in the appendix, however it seems like every violation of the assumptions does not have an impact since I only interpret the coefficients. E.g. violation of normality residuals and constant-variance only biases the estimators.

Comment: Violation of normality can inflate the coefficient's significance, not only make it biased. Also, bias can be important in normative economics etc. So, the main reason to omit these details might be that you trust an author that he did his due diligence, and the results are robust. The subject is economics, so you're interested in findings, usually, not the techniques.

Comment: Also, most methods are robust to some violations in their assumptions, so, with enough and accurate data, there's that as well.

Comment: For a lot of outcomes in the medical field we know that key assumptions tend to be reasonable for certain outcomes. Aadditionally, if you want type I error control, you should not do a pre test of normality to decide between a model with normal residuals and e.g. a rank based method.